# does a loop of async method results need to be aggregated into a thread-safe collection?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, thread-safety

Let's say I have a scenario where I've created some looping logic and within the loop, I aggregate the results into an outer list. I know that in this scenario the results of a Parallel.ForEach() need to be put in a thread-safe collection like ConcurrentBag instead of a List. Is this practice also true for results returned from async methods? Or is it safe to aggregate results from a loop of async methods into a standard List?

**UPDATE**

Interesting test: I ran a test where I simply added 1M Tuple to a ConcurrentBag and the same test for a List. The List test completed in 480ms whereas the ConcurrentBag test completed in 777. So a List is almost 40% faster than a ConcurrentBag with 1M inserts.  I tried the same test with 250K rows and the ConcurrentBag test completed in 140 whereas the List test finished in 182.  So ConcurrentBag is almost 25% faster for 250K inserts.  The List would most likely be faster if the insert scenario could be done as an AddRange(), but otherwise, ConcurrentBag is faster if inserts need to be done incremenatlly for a result set < 250K.  Has this been your experience as well?  Any idea why ConcurrentBag is relatively faster than List for the smaller result set but relatively slower for the larger result set?

Comment: Just apply the usual test: will any thread be writing to the list while another thread is using the list? If the answer is no, you can use a List.

Comment: well if it's a loop of async methods then each method in the loop will execute asyncronously so it seems like it could certainly be possible for 2 different iterations of the async method to try to add different items to the list at the same time.  so I guess the answer here is to use a ConcurrentBag right?

Comment: The computation of results from `await` (and any subsequent code) may run on a different thread, but `await` by itself doesn't make things run in parallel--everything still runs serially unless you use `Parallel.ForEach()` or some similar parallelizing code.

Comment: If you put a memory barrier around the list accesses (reads and writes, because torn reads are just as dangerous as clobbering writes), you're safe. However, that's what the thread-safe collections do, effectively, so just use one of those.

Comment: @dodexahedron Memory barriers wouldn't be useful here; they don't synchronize access to the list, they just prevent instruction reordering on the processor. Even with a memory barrier, a timing issue is still possible.

Comment: The answer to this question depends strongly on your type of [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx). In WinForms and ASP.NET, you are probably safe. In a console application, or if you are using .NET Core, you are probably not safe.

Comment: interesting sounds like for my scenario I should add items to a ConcurrentBag to be on the safe side.  it may have a very small performance impact compared to a list but at least I can rest assured that the final data set will be correct

Comment: Use `ConcurrentBag` when collection updated by many threads. Asynchronous (for example access of external resources like database, webservice etc) methods will be executed on the same thread - so you should be good with just `List<T>`. But for more specific answer you need provide some example of what you trying to do

Comment: @Fabio That's an interesting explanation.  So it sounds like there's no need to use ConcurrentBag as opposed to List unless my code is performing some type of operation which uses functionality within the System.Threading namespace.  Is this correct?

Comment: In the context you gave - yes. Use  "concurrent" collections when try can be updated from more then one thread.